# Set custom creation timestamp or modify creation timestamp for product

Tags: magento2, product, datetime

Magento 2.1.1.

Is there any way to set custom `created_at` attribute on newly created product? I used method `$product->setCreatedAt($date)` before saving it. Value is set on product object, but finally when saving it into db, mysql mechanism is trigger, which sets current timestamp, not mine. I logged sql queries, and field `created_at` is not in `insert` into `catalog_product_entity`, so it's actually normal that mysql fills that field with default value.

Only way I could modify it was pure sql, but it is not a way to go.

Comment: Why do you need change time of product creation/modification?

Comment: its data migration, and timestamps from previous db are meant to be created_at timestamps